# Sphinx search for product & version number

Tags: php, sphinx

I need to build a simple search engine using Sphinx that would search for products and version numbers (which are strings). For example if I have in my index:

- title = Product Name
- version = 1.2.3
- title = Some Other Product
- version = 2.5 beta
- title = Yet another Product
- version = 1.2.4 alpha

So what I want to achieve is:

- Query "product 1.2" should match product 1 & 3 (version 1.2 should be matched as substring of 1.2.3 and 1.2.4)
- Query "product" should match all 3 products
- Query "beta" should match product 2
- Query "1.2.4" should match only 3rd product

etc.

Which configuration settings are important in order to achieve this? I tried changing quite a few configuration variables (ignore chars, blend chars etc.) but nothing gave me the result I want...

Answer (score 0):

```
charset_table = english, U+2E
min_prefix_len = 1
```

And then rewrite the query to automatically attach a * to the end digits

```
$query = preg_replace('/\b(\d+[\.\d]*)\b/','$1*',$query);
```

---

The only problem is that searching `1.2` would still match say `1.20.2`. Should be possible to work around by zero padding (using regex_filter to padd in the index) but thats a lot more work.